# Set the value for an hidden form element

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

i am using HTMLUNit to set the value of a form hidden element as below.

```
HtmlHiddenInput hidden  = (HtmlHiddenInput) page.get("someid");
            hidden.setValueAttribute(seriesName);
```

But this does not work as expected and throw an castException.

I have div element like follows

```
<div class="myclass">
<form:hidden id="someid" htmlEscape="true"/>
</div>
```

How can i set the value for that hidden form id using HTMLUNIT.
Thanks.

Comment: This is java code, not javascript.

Comment: You had a tag for `jQuery`! So asked!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use HtmlHiddenInput. If you are getting a cast exception, use a base object, as DomElement.

```
DomElement myInput = page.getElementById("someid");
myInput.setAttribute("value", seriesName);
```

So with any html dom element, the value attribute will be set to `seriesName`